# Type-checking does not constrain type with generic extends

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

A minimal reproduction:

```
export declare type ExcludeFunctions<T, K extends keyof T> = T[K] extends Function ? never : (K extends symbol ? never : K);

const myAppId: ExcludeFunctions<{ appId: string }, "appId"> = "appId";

class BaseResource {
    appId: string
    constructor(appId: string) {
        this.appId = appId
    }
}

const myAppId2: ExcludeFunctions<BaseResource, "appId"> = "appId";

class MyBaseResourceThing<U extends BaseResource> {
    method() {
        // errors out
        const myAppId3: ExcludeFunctions<U, "appId"> = "appId";
        console.log(myAppId3)
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Type '"appId"' is not assignable to type 'ExcludeFunctions<U, "appId">'.(2322)
```

Why does `myAppId3` not compile? `U` extends `BaseResource` so the type should be constrained.

Comment: This is because `U` is a subtype of class `BaseResource`. It means that it is not equal to `BaseResource`. `U` might be `BaseResource & {_tag:"Hello"}`. Treat `U` as a blackbox

Comment: I don't think that's true, because the `extends` keyword implies a type constraint on `BaseResource`, so `appId` has to be a string`.

Comment: The `appId` property has to be assignable to `string`, but it could be all kinds of wacky narrower things like `string & {(): void}` or `never`.  Even if it turns out that you design your types so carefully that `ExcludeFunctions<U, "appId">` will definitely be `"appId"` no matter what `U` is, we can't expect the compiler to figure that out. [Observe](https://tsplay.dev/Nabaym). I'm happy to write this up as an answer (with more details) if that addresses your question, but if there's something still missing, let me know.

Comment: I think I get it. Thanks @jcalz!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, the compiler is unable to say much about a type which depends on an as-yet unspecified [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter.  Inside the implementation of `method()`, the type parameter `U` is unspecified (it is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `BaseResource`, but it could be any subtype of `BaseResource`).  The type `ExcludeFunctions<U, "appId">` is therefore a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depends on an unspecified generic type parameter.  And the compiler essentially *defers* evaluation of such types.  Meaning that the compiler cannot verify if any specific type is assignable to it, and so it complains.

There are a bunch of issues in GitHub where this is the underlying situation, see [ms/TS#43846](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43846) or [ms/TS#28884](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28884) or [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912), etc.

So, even if you could perform some analysis on `ExcludeFunctions<U, "appId">` and conclude that `"appId"` *must* be assignable to it, the compiler wouldn't be able to see it and you'd need to use something like a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to work around it:

```
class MyBaseResourceThing<U extends BaseResource> {
    method(): ExcludeFunctions<U, "appId"> { 
        const myAppId3 = "appId" as ExcludeFunctions<U, "appId">;
        return myAppId3;
    }
}
```

---

In order to do this kind of analysis better, the compiler would either need to waste a lot of time evaluating types that do not turn out to be reducible in any way, or it would have to have some very good heuristics to know when to try... and the compiler is unfortunately not yet as intelligent as a human being.  Note that even human beings aren't necessarily the best at this type of higher order analysis.  Case in point, the type `"appId"` is actually not guaranteed to be assignable to `ExcludeFunctions<U, "appId">` in your example, because `U` can have a more specific type for the `appId` property than just `string`.  It can be, for example, [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).  Or something like this:

```
declare class Foo extends BaseResource {
    appId: string & { (): void }; // not really possible at runtime but a valid TS type
}
const a = new MyBaseResourceThing<Foo>().method() // a is of type never, 
// but "appId" is not assignable to never
```

Here `U` has been specified with `Foo`, whose `appId` property is both a `string` and a function (basically `never` but not statically reduced to that by the compiler), and so `ExcludeFunctions<U, "appId">` is `never`, and you can't assign `"appId"` to it safely.

So in this specific case the compiler is technically correct to warn you.  Of course pragmatically speaking you're not going to see `string`-function-monsters in your code.  That means you should probably just use a type assertion as shown above and move on.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AYwDYEMrDjAnmbAURDQFckAxUgO2RgEsJqBnAHgBUAaOAaTlBjBqCZnADWwXBABmcdgD44AXgBQcdXIDaPALr8Qg4aKq0GTOAH441YADdgUOAC44ACj4ChIuM1wBbACMIVEtrOwdnXgBKAG4VFWQmZng-XABBMDAASQQXYjJKGjpGFlYAbzh0TJyXZKh6agBzOABfbgAiKuyEdsUlOE7qnriEjGZRACF0ZmAAJWBmCFIoZGwytQ0ump8YeqaN9USWXdI6aFct3J29xqi4dY1HnAALemYAOkvlSqGD1pUWvEjsk4KkMt0AEx5EiocjAEzFJKsKYzeaLZarDqXXrfQbddojNDTUQAWVwKLmCyWK2A7FeTVYAFV9IZvBS0dTVooHho-MAYM8IAhXFFoQV4UUzKVGVihjiKgB6BVwVgAWlVoPQEhebxw+Gwtje9ACqGw0igED8cCWMGY9CQTw0f0ewJS6SGAGZcdjKqJ8rDCqYSmwZQNsfI4o71FgYMtqKD3d0PZGNIDASokESsHAieM4BQIBAWV5JtNKeiafc-pdarsGs0AGT3NyiuC2CD21oxOBK6wQeBYdCoVC4OCQcbG02VAc0Bh8uABUjwdBtoed9gAZT1BABCSSy++NgA7nAyeyqRjafTGqwCxB5CL3nyBUKRT3lSvdTJt9gbPYoNwi7wHiOTtHAurUP2vp2o01DoCa2AwEWf4OEAA)